# E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate

Tags: software-installation

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:

 software-properties-common

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

How can i fix this error?

Answer (score 71):

Install `software-properties-common` by running,

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

`software-properties-common` package is an alternate one for `python-software-properties`.

for <= 12.04

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
```

for >= 12.10

```
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

Comment: This is working. but still the sudo apt-get install python-software-properties is not working.

Comment: `python-software-properties` package will only be available for the versions below 12.04.

Comment: @AvinashRaj and what would replace it?

Comment: If you found this when trying to install torch, you'll need to comment the two lines involving `python-software-properties` in `torch/install-deps` after installing `software-properties-common`.

Comment: On Ubuntu 16.04, `dpkg --listfiles python-properties-common` and `dpkg --listfiles software-properties-common` indicates that `python-properties-common` adds files for only Python version 2.7. And, that `software-properties-common` provides files for Python 3.

Answer (score 11):

I had this issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tried several way finally this fixed my issue

```
sudo apt --fix-broken install python-pycurl python-apt
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I have tried so many solution (except the one that leads user to chaos: `apt-get upgrade`). And  finally yours is the solution that worked for me. I guess the `apt` package was broken somewhere..

Answer (score 6):

I was getting started with the torch and faced the error.
Here is how I got it resolved.

1. goto

   > Home -> Torch -> Open `install-deps`

   find the keyword `python-software-properties` and replace it with `software-python-common`, save and exit.
2. install the software-python-common with the command

   ```
   sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
   ```
3. run the command

   ```
   cd ~/torch; bash install-deps;
   ```

You are done!!

Comment: you made a typo in: `software-python-common` (should be `software-properties-common`)

Comment: Please use `software-properties-common` instead of `software-python-common` it works like a charm !

Answer (score 1):

In the executable `install-deps` within `~/torch`, you need to edit it so that every instance of `python-software-properties` should be `software-properties-common`

An easy solution that worked for me would be to just run this simple `python3` script:

```py
with open(PATH_TO_<install-deps>, "r") as f:
    text = f.read()


change = text.replace("python-software-properties", "software-properties-common")


with open(PATH_TO_<install-deps>, "w") as f:
    f.write(change)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my 1st post and I have only used linux for a few weeks so please 
go easy on me =].

If ymin's method hits an error of

> root@my32bitbox:~# sudo apt-get install python-software-properties
>   git-core. Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree
>   Reading state information... Done Package python-software-properties
>   is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean
>   that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available
>   from another source However the following packages replace it:
>   software-properties-common

...  this slightly tweaked line worked for me (note: if it makes any difference...I needed it to install 32-bit dependencies for my own wine build)

```
> sudo apt-get install software-properties-common git-core
```

Answer (score -1):

I also got the same error. 
Open terminal and type below command

```
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
```

then, this

```
sudo apt-get install -y python-software-properties
```

I hope this will work. It worked in my system.