# python-software-properties on ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.04

i couldn't install `python-software-properties` on Ubuntu 
my operating system is Ubuntu 19.10
i tried "`sudo apt-get install python-software-properties`"
but it keeps showing me :

```
package python-software-properties is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  software-properties-common

E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: i am trying to install angular 8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422975/e-package-python-software-properties-has-no-installation-candidate)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Then you should install the replacement with:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install software-properties-common
```

For me it seems that you are trying to obtain the `add-apt-repository` command which is contained in [*software-properties-common* package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=add-apt-repository&mode=exactfilename&suite=disco&arch=any).