# Missing dependencies for Discord

Tags: 20.04, dpkg

I wanted to download Discord for my Ubuntu, so I downloaded the file from Discord's website. However, when I tried to install it, I got the following missing dependencies error:

```
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of discord:
 discord depends on libatomic1; however:
  Package libatomic1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libgconf-2-4; however:
  Package libgconf-2-4 is not installed.
 discord depends on libappindicator1; however:
  Package libappindicator1 is not installed.
 discord depends on libc++1; however:
  Package libc++1 is not installed.
```

When I tried to install `libgconf-2-4` I got another error:

```
Package libgconf-2-4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libgconf-2-4' has no installation candidate
```

How can I install Discord?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [E: Package 'python-software-properties' has no installation candidate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/422975/e-package-python-software-properties-has-no-installation-candidate)

Comment: This is more or less a duplicate question

Comment: `sudo snap install discord` or You can install it from the software centre too.

Comment: Does this answer your question ? [Missing dependencies while installing discord on Kali Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/1628501/dependency-error-when-installing-discord)

Comment: You've not said what command you used to install it; `dpkg` for example requires that you've already installed, or install at the same time all *depends* requirements so did you?  or if you use `apt` (or equiv.) they'll be downloaded if available in your sources. We currently don't know your OS & release either.